have used npm create vite@latest but after finishing the compilations am getting a warning
npm warn deprecated 
inflight@1.0.6: this module is not supported, and leaks memory. do not use it. check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.

I was creating react app using vite

Please add what commands did you run and the full output.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If you dig into package-lock.json, you can see that this is because vite is using the @typescript-eslint package, which require an outdated version of eslint, which in turn use an outdated version of file-entry-cache, which use an outdated version of flat-cache, which use an outdated version of rimraf, which use an outdated version of glob, which use inflight@1.0.6.
Unfortunately you have to wait for @typescript-eslint to release a new version that use eslint 9 to get rid of this warning.

but even if I use npx create-react-app the same still happens there

It is also using some outdated version of glob. rimraf and glob are some very common libraries which are widely used by so many packages. With a  full-blown project, chances of some dependencies using one of those are very high. It just takes time for developers to update all dependencies, if that even possible.

what might cause it because initially before I changed windows everything was working well without this problem or could it be caused by new laptop widows 10 have installed

Nothing causes it. It is what it is, the developers haven't upgrade their dependencies. This is not something you can control or fix. This is not an error, just an warning, it doesn't hurt. You can try the overrides method in the other answer, it should be a valid workaround.

TypeScript-ESLint Maintainer here. Ignore the warning - it's useless here. It's a transitive dependency 7 layers deep and it's only a deprecation warning. The code paths that use rimraf (and thus inflight) aren't even active in most eslint setups. The warning is just noise and spreading FUUD.

@BradZacher Is there a plan to remove such a small dependency that is causing this to keep the Node ecosystem cleaner for everyone? It looks really bad on npm, React, and Typescript's part to see such a warning. No developer small or large should make it a habit to just "ignore the warning" of a memory leak, even if the dependency isn't being used. This reaches way more than just React apps too.

@IanSmith It's entirely up to you and your setup. This warning comes from v8 of ESLint. If you don't update then you're going to have to accept that the warning exists and that it's a fear-mongering message that doesn't actually impact you. Feel free to take it up with ESLint core. Here is their issue tracker showing issues about this dependency: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues?q=sort%3Aupdated-desc%20is%3Aissue%20inflight%20created%3A%3E%3D2024-01-01

@BradZacher Oh, I was not aware v9 fixes the issue, that should be the suggested answer here, yeah?

@IanSmith yes and no. The migration to v9 isn't easy - there are many breaking changes and as such many 3rd party plugins still dot support it. Additionally v9 requires a migration to flat configs - which is not possible for all users. It's one solution to silence the warnings but not one many codebases can do.

In my project i solved forcing npm with some overrides, and all seems working...
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "eslint": "9.3.0",
    ...
  },
  "overrides":{
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin":{
      "eslint": "$eslint"
    },
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": {
      "eslint": "$eslint"
    },
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": {
      "eslint": "$eslint"
    }
  }


Open CMD and type this command npx create-react-app cynor(your project name)
-

List item

